# Why is XEmacs refusing to automatically syntax-highlight a specific .pl file?

Tags: perl, syntax-highlighting, xemacs

I edited a `perl script` recently and since the edits, `XEmacs` refuses to do the `cperl-mode` syntax highlighting automatically.

I have been able to force the buffer to do the syntax highlighting in 2 different ways:

- by selecting `Options->Syntax Highlighting->Lazy Lock`
- by running `M-x font-lock-fontify-buffer`

For the life of me, I have not been able to figure out why these work-arounds are necessary.  Other `.pl files` open with syntax highlighting just fine.  The script runs, so it's valid code.

I tried updating.  I tried adding things to the `init.el file` to run the `font-lock-fontify-buffer` command upon opening a file.  After trying a bunch of things, I finally just blew away the `init.el file` away and it still opens other `.pl files` fine, but still chokes on this one file.

Whenever I open the file, the last status message printed is `"Loading cperl-mode...done"` (same as other `.pl files` without any errors).

Another thing that fails to happen is the window doesn't automatically resize to 80 columns.

**question**

Any idea why this is happening and how to get the syntax highlighting to work on ALL .pl files?

Comment: Is the file unusually large?

Comment: Yeah, actually, it's my largest script by a few thousand lines.  I'm in the process of breaking it up.  Might take awhile though. Is there a limit for xemacs?  Current size: 10,407 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use XEmacs, but GNU Emacs has a `font-lock-maximum-size` variable.  XEmacs probably has the same or a similar setting. You may need to increase that, or just set it to `nil`.

Comment: Yes!  That did it: `(setq font-lock-maximum-size nil)`. Thanks so much!